# Localization not working in Marshmallow and below versions

Tags: android, localization

I added German strings in values-de folder. It is working in 7.0 and above version of android devices but not working in 6.0 and below version. I implemented one sample app,in that I have added the same German strings file, it was working fine, but not working in my application. I did not understand the root cause for this issue.

below is my gradle file, please provide answer for this issue.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.titanfireworks"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 11
    versionName "2.2.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportPackageVersion"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportPackageVersion" //This is added in Carousel li
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportPackageVersion"
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
```

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Are all strings not working or just some of them?

Comment: All are not working. And I used same german strings file instead of english, it was working, but not working when I used it from values-de folder and working fine in 7.0 and above versions.

Comment: how are you switching between languages.. do you have in app setings

Comment: Yes..I am switching laguage from mobile settings. not from application, in application I just added strings file.

Comment: Is there any problem with gradle file, like compile version sdk version??, I tested with compiler version 26. still not working.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support
It could be a problem in selecting the language. What "language" are you selecting from mobile settings?

Comment: If it is problem with the selection, It should not come in 7.0 and above version. am I correct?

Comment: try what is your locale in the 6.0 device after changing the language getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

Comment: It is showing getResources().getConfiguration().locale is German.

Comment: Could you try by adding a folder "values-b+de" and keeping your strings.xml there?

Comment: Everything looks fine , res/values-de should work fine. This may be stupid suggestion try cleaning the project after you added your resources.

Comment: @Bharath Kumar No luck.

Comment: @Pop cleaned many times, still same issue.

Comment: Yeah @Pop, values-de folder should be sufficient. There is some more enhancements in Android 7.0. Check "Language and region" in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#QualifierRules Not sure if there is a bug in it.

Comment: @SarithaG Could you try completely uninstalling the application, rebooting your phone and then doing a fresh install.

Comment: strings file contains some ASCII char's. but the same file was working fine in some other sample application.

Comment: the problem is in 6.0 device . the changes you mentioned are from 7.0.

Comment: @SarithaG if its ok for you post string file

Comment: Yes @Pop, the changes i mentioned are in 7.0, so i'm not sure if the there is a bug in 6.0. Ideally it should work.

Comment: the problem is in Lollipop and Marshamallow versions. and there is no prblm with strings file bcoz I copied the entire file in sample app, it was working. Problem with app only, but if it is with app then it not work in 7.0 also. I am not understanding the root cause.